# Use bsdiff being the source and target file the same one. Other difference algorithms suitable for this?

Tags: c, diff

I am trying to patch a file using bsdiff, my problem is that I have to do it having few memory available. According to this constraint I need to modify the source file with the patch in order to get the target file.
Bsdiff basic are as follows:

*header*: not very relevant in this explanation.

*Control data block*:

- mixlen-> number of bytes to be modified combining the bytes from the source
  file and the bytes obtained from the diff block.
- copylen-> number of bytes to be added. This is totally new extra data
  that need to be added to our file. This bytes are read from the
  extra block.
- seeklen-> number used to know which we have to read from the source file.

*Compressed control block.*

*Compressed diff block.*

*Compressed extra block.*

```
Patch file format:
  0        8       BSDIFF_CONFIG_MAGIC
  8        8       X
  16       8       Y
  24       8       sizeof(newfile)
  32       X       control block
  32+X     Y       diff block
  32+X+Y   ???     extra block
  with control block a set of triples (x,y,z) meaning "add x bytes
  from oldfile to x bytes from the diff block; copy y bytes from the
  extra block; seek forwards in oldfile by z bytes".
```

So the problem is that bsdiff considers I always have the source file without any modification, so it uses it to modify data that I have already modified (if I consider the source the same file as the target). Firstly I tried to reorder the modifications to do, but in some cases these modifications affect memory that will be used in the future for another modification. Maybe the algorithm is not suitable what I want.

**Does exist another algorithm suitable for this? Is there any implementation of BSDIFF or similar doing what I need?**

Before going more in depth with Bsdiff I did some research, finding VCDIFF(used by Xdelta) but it also seems to have the same behavior I haven't dug into the code though, so I don't know yet if it generate the patch in the same what as Bsdiff does.

Another point to remark would be I am trying to implement it in **C**.

Edited 04/10/2016:
I have tried to reorder the patch, because having the addresses to modify ordered from smaller to the bigger I thought I could handle this problem storing the original memory data into a buffer until the next modification which requires that original data had been done, but it seems that the patch order is important also, maybe in Bsdiff it modifies several times the same part of memory until it gets the right data. Any idea will be very welcome if someone knows about this.

Best regards,

Iván

Answer (score 0):

We cannot eliminate the dependency on source data without impacting the compressed delta size. So, you will need to have source data unmodified to make BSDIFF work in the scenario you explained.